# How to query mongodb from groovy/grails?

Tags: mongodb, grails

Do I have to have a domain object to query `mongodb`?

What if I just want some raw data to be displayed? What would be the syntax to query `mongodb` from my controller?

I tried

```
"def var = db.nameOfMyCollection.find()"
```

but it says no such property as db in my controller class.

I know that my application is connecting to the database because I am monitoring `mongo server` log and it increases the number of connections by one when I launch my grails app.

Comment: Where did you find out that db.nameOfMyCollection.find() is the correct way how to query a database in Grails?

Comment: Did you use any field in your query? Have a look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: actually that is my problem, I do not know how to reference my database in the proper way. At this point I only know that my application is connecting to it but I don't know how to run any Mongodb functions on it from within groovy.

Comment: Then start following the tutorial, no way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have added mongodb java driver dependency in build config and refreshed your dependencies.

Create a grails service named **MongoService.groovy** and put the following code.

Dont forget to import mongodb

```
package com.organisation.project

import com.mongodb.*


class MongoService {
    private static MongoClient mongoClient
    private static host = "localhost"    //your host name
    private static port = 27017      //your port no.
    private static databaseName = "your-mongo-db-name"

    public static MongoClient client() {
        if(mongoClient == null){
            return new MongoClient(host,port)
        }else {
            return mongoClient
        }
    }

    public DBCollection collection(collectionName) {
        DB db = client().getDB(databaseName)
        return db.getCollection(collectionName)
    }
}
```

We can now use this MongoService in our controllers or other services.

Now you can do following stuff in your controller.

Dont forget to import mongodb.DBCursor

```
package com.organisation.project



import com.mongodb.DBCursor

class YourControllerOrService {

    def mongoService    //including Mongo service 

    def method(){
        def collection = mongoService.collection("your-collection-name")
        DBCursor cursor =  collection.find()
        try{
            while(cursor.hasNext()){
                def doc = cursor.next()
                println doc     //will print raw data if its in your database for that collection
                }

         }finally {
                  cursor.close()
         }

    }
}
```

For more info Refer [mongodb java docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/)

Comment: Sawpnil, that looks like exactly what I need. I totally understand the code and why it would work. But because I am so new with Grails, I am not sure how to add the java mongodb driver to my project. I played with trying to do just that and gave up after a few hours yesterday, I even tried on how to use Gmongo but that is a similar procedure so I had to give up there as well. Any suggestion on this? Thanks so much.

Comment: I could go either way on this answer. If you're only interested in using the Mongo Java API, and you are worried about bloating your application, I think this is the correct approach. However, for a quicker start, I would recommend the MongoDB GORM Plugin, as it will essentially provide the Service you describe.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got that GORM plugin installed but I was too dumb to realize that in doing so, I already have imported the java mongodb driver. As a newbie, that is what I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @MoeB when you said in your question that "my application is connecting to the database because I am monitoring mongo server log and it increases the number of connections by one when I launch my grails app", I got that you have added mongodb java driver. Having said that MongoDB GORM Plugin looks more promising with GORM features.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, solved.

This is how you go about accessing the database.

```
import com.mongodb.*
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB("db");
```

I actually solved it using Java and then pasted it into groovy and it works there as well which shouldn't come as a surprise. The difference is that in Java you actually have to import the jar driver, but in Grails, you install the Mongo GORM plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the [MongoDB GORM Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb), if you have domain classes in your grails application, you can use them as you would with any relational db backend.

However, per [this documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html), you can access the low-level Mongo API in any controller or service by first declaring a property `mongo`, just as you would a service, then getting the database you are targeting:

```
def mongo
def myAction = {
    def db = mongo.getDB("mongo")
    db.languages.insert([name: 'Groovy'])
}
```