# Grails Mongodb static collections access

Tags: mongodb, grails

I have a Grails application that uses Mongodb to persist domain classes. I also have some collections in Mongodb that aren't modeled after my domain classes because they are just static data like telephone codes and currency exchange rates. How do I go about accessing these collections via my code since they aren't modeled after domain classes, I cannot use GORM's finders to retrieve these data correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GORM is not an option.
Add mongo java driver dependency in buildConfig.groovy like
 `runtime 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.3'`, refresh your dependencies and **[then follow this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617597/how-to-query-mongodb-from-groovy-grails/23625508#23625508)** which shows how to access such collections from mongodb which is not modelled after domain classes.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Thanks for pointing that out. Yes MongoDB GORM looks promising. Have you tried that out to access collections for data which is not modeled with domain classes?

Comment: No. But what you exactly get is the underlying driver instance of type `com.mongodb.Mongo`. You can do everything with that.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg i think owner of question has used Grails Mongo Low Level API [Refer his question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24392264/grails-mongo-low-level-api).

Answer (score 0):

The Gorm Plugin offers access to the low level API. Have a look at http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongodb/manual/guide/4.%20Low-level%20API.html