# Grails Mongo Low Level API

Tags: mongodb, grails

What would be the equivalent of this line in groovy code when using the Mongo low level API?

```
 db.countrycodes.findOne({"Country":"Antarctica"})
```

This line successfully finds the appropriate record for me in the Mongo shell but I tried many variations of it in my controller method and I keep getting NULL. Heres is my current attempt which is failing:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("twcdb");
    DBCollection coll = db.getCollection('countrycodes')
    println coll.find("Country":"Antarctica")
```

I know my collection and db is non NULL because when I do `find()` I do get a valid cursor back through which I can print the first record in collection. Here is the record I am trying to find:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539848b2119918654e7e90b1"),
    "Country" : "Antarctica",
    "Alpha2" : "AQ",
    "Aplha3" : "ATA",
    "Numeric" : "10",
    "FIPS" : "AY",
    "IGA" : ""
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your controller code?

Comment: @Lalit Agarwal Posted updated as requested.

Comment: @Christian P If I try that I 'null' printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
def cursor =  coll.find()
    def obj = cursor.next()
    while (obj.Country != 'Antarctica') {
        obj = cursor.next()
    }
```

It is inefficient, you will have to traverse the whole collection everytime to find a record, but it will end up with 'obj' being the record you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and see if it works.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Country", "Antartica");

def cursor = coll.find(query)

try {
  while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
  }
} finally {
   cursor.close();
}
```

For more info look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: cusor.next() gives null.